# Neo4j Cypher Pattern Comprehension and collection join

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following Cypher Pattern Comprehension:

```
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)  
WHERE NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) AND ch1.type = 'CHILD'
| {characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id),  value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: v1.totalHistoryValues, description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

where `parentD` and `childD` are the variables from outer query scope.

Right now I need to improve this Pattern Comprehension with additional nodes:

```
(childD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch2:Characteristic)<-[v2:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)
WHERE NOT ((ch2)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) AND ch2.type = 'OWN'
```

in order to be able also return `Characteristics`(`ch2`) from this query and their values(`v2`).

Please help to extend the mentioned query in order to return this information under the same `valuedCharacteristics`

**UPDATED**

I have updated comprehension  to the following:

```
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch2:Characteristic)<-[v2:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)  
  WHERE 
    NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) AND ch1.type = 'CHILD' AND 
    NOT ((ch2)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) AND ch2.type = 'OWN' | 
  { characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id), value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: v1.totalHistoryValues, description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode, 
    childCharacteristicId: toInt(ch2.id), childValue: v2.value, childAvailable: v2.available, childTotalHistoryValues: v2.totalHistoryValues, childDescription: v2.description, childValueType: ch2.valueType, childVisualMode: ch2.visualMode 
  } 
] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

but right now it always returns empty collection.

I may be wrong but I think the reason is that the following query:

```
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch2:Characteristic)<-[v2:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)
```

can't return the result in some cases.. for example when `ch2` is present and `ch1` is absent.

Comment: In the second pattern comprehension, you have `(childD)` on both sides of the pattern. Is that intended?

Comment: yes, it means that `Decision` defines `Characteristic` and then place a value for itself on this `Characteristic` (in this case `type = 'OWN'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern comprehension should work (but it will generate an empty collection unless the entire pattern is matched):

```
[(parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch2:Characteristic)<-[v2:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)
  WHERE
    NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) AND ch1.type = 'CHILD' AND
    NOT ((ch2)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) AND ch2.type = 'OWN' |
  {
    characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id), value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: v1.totalHistoryValues, description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode,
    childCharacteristicId: toInt(ch2.id), childValue: v2.value, childAvailable: v2.available, childTotalHistoryValues: v2.totalHistoryValues, childDescription: v2.description, childValueType: ch2.valueType, childVisualMode: ch2.visualMode
  }
] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

[UPDATED]

However, if you want to always get the "parent" data, but optionally get the "child" data (if it exists), then you could switch to using `MATCH` and `OPTIONAL MATCH`. For example:

```
MATCH (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)
WHERE NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) AND ch1.type = 'CHILD'
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch2:Characteristic)<-[v2:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)
WHERE NOT ((ch2)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) AND ch2.type = 'OWN'
RETURN COLLECT({
  parent: {characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id), value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: v1.totalHistoryValues, description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode},
  child: {characteristicId: toInt(ch2.id), value: v2.value, available: v2.available, totalHistoryValues: v2.totalHistoryValues, description: v2.description, valueType: ch2.valueType, visualMode: ch2.visualMode}
}) AS valuedCharacteristics
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated the comprehension to this one(please see my updated question) but unfortunately it always returns empty collection now

Comment: I may be wrong but I think the reason is that the provided query can't return the result in some cases.. for example when ch2 is present and ch1 is absent.

Comment: Correct. As I indicated, it requires the *entire* pattern to match.

Comment: Thanks, gotcha.. how to rewrite this query in order to work in these cases ?

Comment: Thanks ! one more issue is that ch1 and ch2 can exist independently. Does OPTIONAL MATCH instead of MATCH (for parent data) in the query beginning can solve this ?

Comment: No, since the two clauses share the same `childD` variable.

Comment: Could you please show how to correctly handle this case ?

Comment: I mean - I need ch1 or ch2 or both of them if both present

Comment: Or maybe this case will work on the current query.. I have to try it

Comment: I think it would be better (more efficient and much less complex) to first use my updated answer (to find all `ch1` and optionally associated child `ch2`). Them if that returns an empty collection, do a separate query to find just the `ch2`.